# What is adb device -l listing?

Tags: android, adb

```
adb devices -l
devices [-l]                  - list all connected devices
                                ('-l' will also list device qualifiers)
```

When I execute it I am getting like

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached 
Medfield14ABxxxx       device usb:2-1.5
Ztedfield14Axxxx       device usb:2-1.6
emulator-5554          device
015d2994ec2xxx         device usb:2-1.5 product:nakasi model:Nexus_7 device:grouper


Medfield14ABA072       device usb:1-1.1 ( changing to different port)
```

when I change to different port its displaying the bus number as 1 and 2 as displayed in `lsusb` command

what is this device usb:2-**1.5** ,**1.6** ,**1.1** ?

so what this -l will do,whats the exact meaning for the device qualifiers?

I tried with `lsusb` but the information is different that adb device -l.

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 18d1:4e42 Google Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 17ef:7470 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 7):

It's the path of the device in the USB subsystem.  For example `2-1.5` means controller 2, port 1, port 5.  Between the two ports there must be a hub.  This seems to match up with your `lsusb` output, which indicates `Bus 002 Device 001` is a hub.

To find this out, I had a dig int the `adb` source code, and found this is referred to as the `devpath`.  You can see how it is found in [`usb_linux.c`](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/38219ee6116943269b0501a1a0210c76e2ba69c3/adb/usb_linux.c).  In summary, when a device is found the code resolves the symbolic link at `/sys/dev/char/<major>:<minor>` and takes the last path component as the `devpath`.  If you run:

```
$ ls -l /sys/dev/char |grep usb
```

you can see the links point to `/sys/devices/platform/...` and you should see some of these paths end with components matching the devices.  Finally I found a description of what these paths mean in [this posting](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-usb-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg16895.html) by Alan Stern.

Comment: Great stuff.  One last question: How do you relate this back to the devices listed by `lsusb`? For instance, `lsusb` lists "Bus 002 Device 052" and `fastboot devices -l` lists "usb:2-1.7", how do I connect the dots?

Comment: @EdwardFalk     did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem when automatically mount many devices. After much digging I found how to find the connection between the

```
adb devices -l 
List of devices attached 
XXXXXXXX       device usb:9-1.4 product:XXXXXXXXXXX
.............
XXXXXXXX       device usb:3-1 product:XXXXXXXXXXX
```

and

```
lsusb
Bus 009 Device 005: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
.............
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
```

our MTP devices can be seen using the:

```
ls /dev | grep libmtp-
libmtp-3-1
.............
libmtp-9-1.4
```

and they on a bus:

```
ls -l /dev/libmtp-9-1.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /dev/libmtp-9-1.4 -> bus/usb/009/005

ls -l /dev/libmtp-3-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /dev/libmtp-3-1 -> bus/usb/003/003
```